# SCNAction.rotate clips through other nodes

Tags: ios, scenekit, scnnode

I have a node (nodeCollection) that has an SCNNode as a childNode which is created like this:

```
let boxGeo = SCNBox(width: 1, height: 1, length: 1, chamferRadius: 0.0)
let node = SCNNode(geometry: boxGeo)
node.physicsBody = SCNPhysicsBody.staticBody()
```

I am also creating the redbox node like so:

```
let redBox = SCNNode()
redBox.geometry = SCNBox(width: 0.5, height: 0.5, length: 0.5, chamferRadius: 0.1)
redBox.geometry?.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = UIColor.redColor()
redBox.position = SCNVector3Make(0, 1, -2)
redBox.physicsBody = SCNPhysicsBody.dynamicBody()
```

I am then running the below code to make the nodes rotate

```
let rotateAction = SCNAction.rotateByAngle(CGFloat(M_PI_2), aroundAxis: SCNVector3Make(0, 0, 1), duration: 0.15)
rotateAction.timingMode = .EaseInEaseOut
nodeCollection.runAction(rotateAction)
```

I then add both the nodeCollection and redBox as childNodes to the SCNScene

But as you can see when I perform the rotate on the nodeCollection the physics of the redBox doesn't hold.  **The physics works when the red box drops onto the scene as it stops and rests on the bluebox**

How can I fix this so that when the blue box rotates, it doesn't just clip through the redBox

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing the physicsBody type of the blue box to `kinematic`, static bodies are not supposed to move.

The different types are explained here:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SceneKit/Reference/SCNPhysicsBody_Class/#//apple_ref/c/tdef/SCNPhysicsBodyType